# Unable To Connect Two DV Tape Decks Via Firewire on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, firewire

I'm trying to connect, and record from, two DV tape decks that are attached via Firewire.

Here are my specs:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 
Firewire Card: LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller (rev 08)
DV Tape Deck 1: Sony HVR-M15AE 
DV Tape Deck 2: Sony DCR-TR7000E
```

I'm using DVRescue to capture from the tape decks (https://github.com/mipops/dvrescue). This has a command for listing the connected tape decks `dvrescue --list_devices` and should support a connection to multiple tape decks. I can get one device connected and working, but it won't connect both at the same time.

Is there an alternative way for me to check for the connection of the DV tape decks, without using DVRescue? That would help me identify if the issue is with DVRescue or the firewire itself.

If I'm not able to have both devices connected at once, is there a way for me to switch between them, aside from unplugging the firewire cable?